# A temporary mailbox/mail receiving server in Python

Tags: python, email, smtpd

Need sugestions on how to implement/what to use/what or about what to read in order to know how, a mail server in Python, which would let me to generate temporary mailboxes.

Let’s say I have a domain test.com, I would like to be able to setup for example a mailbox temporary1@test.com, which would receive and store mails (even in txt files).

What do I need to be able to do that?
(I’m interested in links or explanations rather than implementations)

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 ships with the [`smtpd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html) module that can be used to implement this.

You'll probably want to trivially subclass `smtpd.SMTPServer` (maybe even derive from or at least be inspired by `smtpd.DebuggingServer`, but have it print out to files instead of standard output).

Once that's up and running (you can use the `smtplib` clients to test things out), you'll need to have that server process running on a machine on port 25 (the standard SMTP port), and you'll need to point the MX record of `test.com` to that machine's address.

Comment: Thank you, so in user@test.com, “user” part is “passed” by DNS (if properly configured) to the website’s mailserver, am I right?

Comment: Not quite. DNS doesn't care about the local part (`user@`) at all.